# Parameterizing a specflow step with keyword string from example step

Tags: specflow

I am new to specflow, want help with a specflow scenario like the one below.

```
Scenario Outline: Error messages validation for maximum allowed term rule
Given a <product>  
When term exceeds the max allowed term 
Then this <errormessage> is displayed

Examples: 
| product    | errormessage                 |
| ProductA   | This is an error message 1   |
| ProductB   | This is an error message 2   |
| ProductC   | This is an error message 3   |
```

For the last step definition "*Then this errormessage is displayed *" step, I want to reuse an existing binding method

"**Then this (.***) is displayed"

This existing binding method takes a string as a parameter (expected error message) and asserts it against the actual message picked form the app under test.

But when I use the method as is - its unable to pass the error message content as an array of strings . Would someone be able to help me to understand what do I need to do to make it work ?

Binding method example below . The step Then this is displayed is not able to recognize this binding, its asking me to write another method.

```
[Then(@"this ""(.*)"" is displayed")]
public void ThenErrorMessageIsDisplayed(string errorMessage)
{
    var msg = uServiceSupport.GetMessages(responseData);
    var found = new JObject();

    // due to multiple error and warning messages
    foreach (var elem in msg)
    {
        if (elem["message"].ToString().Contains(errorMessage))
            found = (JObject)elem;
    }

    try
    {                
        Assert.IsTrue(found.HasValues, "Check if response has warning/error message");
        Assert.AreEqual(errorMessage, found["message"].ToString(), "Check if the error message is {0}", errorMessage);
    }            
    catch (AssertionException)
    {
        Helper.LogInfo(string.Format("Response:\n {0}", JObject.Parse(responseData)));
        throw;
    }

}
```

Comment: please post the code for your existing binding method including attribute and method signature. This should work fine

Comment: Hello @SamHolder I have added my existing binding example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your step regex. you have this:

```
[Then(@"this ""(.*)"" is displayed")]
```

but you try and call it like this:

```
Then this <errormessage> is displayed
```

you do not have consistent usage of the `"`. you either need:

```
[Then(@"this (.*) is displayed")]
```

or

```
Then this "<errormessage>" is displayed
```

Comment: Thank you @Sam Holder - that works :) . Thanks so much for your help